# Message "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter." At Spring Security Jwt

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

In the project, I want to use a spring-security-jwt-1.0.9.RELEASE and I wrote the following code for this purpose:

CORSFilter.java

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

FindDoctorApiConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ir.shaingroup.FindDoctorAPI")
public class FindDoctorApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/lang");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

FindDoctorApiInitializer.java

```
public class FindDoctorApiInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { FindDoctorApiConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new CORSFilter() };
    }

}
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SpringSecurityConfig(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER")
                .and()
                    .withUser("admin").password("123").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                    .withUser("doctor").password("123").roles("DOCTOR")
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("**/oauth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .anonymous().disable()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();

        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));

        return handler;
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAupPVZSSdjwwLiSxkquhS\n" +
            "Udwohh5AiiGxiNUTmCgu+0P7hF5kvrhl+Gm8pTD+Svf5LCZ/uZQeYeND/M9QzCw8\n" +
            "RQZe1kCCwYW0cvNovyXTq37sJM+X5btGHRFOW3hHuHlaar02aPhNdfoULkNUBS0b\n" +
            "h06HemJkv0+pHJ/FjVKu4BycBrMnvwtMhF2kcQCZCJk8HfiPbpLt03YiRkGX3wiR\n" +
            "B9OOMIh5MQQWO/oi5xPvoiXVxBKAaER5QQ+OkGyTgqKM/VMlMqB43ncchTCn2+ZY\n" +
            "9wx5KYWgr87nsTAXDTnWxhe49Fx5hPgfyrhqg4ZC+w/2qQcbBpeEA6nFjDviZfiJ\n" +
            "2QIDAQAB\n" +
            "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    private static final String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAupPVZSSdjwwLiSxkquhSUdwohh5AiiGxiNUTmCgu+0P7hF5k\n" +
            "vrhl+Gm8pTD+Svf5LCZ/uZQeYeND/M9QzCw8RQZe1kCCwYW0cvNovyXTq37sJM+X\n" +
            "5btGHRFOW3hHuHlaar02aPhNdfoULkNUBS0bh06HemJkv0+pHJ/FjVKu4BycBrMn\n" +
            "vwtMhF2kcQCZCJk8HfiPbpLt03YiRkGX3wiRB9OOMIh5MQQWO/oi5xPvoiXVxBKA\n" +
            "aER5QQ+OkGyTgqKM/VMlMqB43ncchTCn2+ZY9wx5KYWgr87nsTAXDTnWxhe49Fx5\n" +
            "hPgfyrhqg4ZC+w/2qQcbBpeEA6nFjDviZfiJ2QIDAQABAoIBAQCLCvDU11yz5f4S\n" +
            "1AqRc2ElsDRi/tiKGGH93w0jL48Toa4nD1F08GbNob78PG7F39bJmEdHPaMGwB9C\n" +
            "oB1Oiwi/R+gVMy4+mi3IHK3LBZ2hCI1jQXGpus6divAiKpkIWSeQtEGAKMtRSHUR\n" +
            "pQtQcDU7uMIt6nW6PNuCgW7vytaYHHN4xqeseUowaSa0x+9arlhpM2D7PnBVt+PN\n" +
            "anl1x3vNNFXmLqHotGY4ZiiG4Vkb4OY1JAMPb6w0YbGaGqEz87b+kaUJdOzGeU/n\n" +
            "Fy/sdsFI5CfZirP0H628w/iurK9eRcHivvgieZKeLailTnJMnmGl5LrkNGsZAHn2\n" +
            "sxgAVPwBAoGBAOqsurjFy30RmFo3LxJ0XLVG/w7OJ6AbF5gIe1+oflG/SPLGKqxo\n" +
            "NV09YaTIfQfAfrHpyykWuAUS33QY7AuY4dRYbcSnHo9zQWrCiBl6pXJhquOuoIDZ\n" +
            "QBvFXGkMtdsYnkKmbj4Sbly/DJZWN9Llypakue5WgZeMdGmxg0K3kwKpAoGBAMuI\n" +
            "NhKJiP17TrVgBsI8W3T6jkTLsmcm0bi3jmmxRcM4sKp0yK+vvZPmlk6qwtn5axTP\n" +
            "HOdsdIh0ZP3DzDPNoc0jJwZqPpOws9Y9Zo8dlLG//5U9k2kPGy2POu6F1XgI8e8x\n" +
            "tI84vufyoscJVTDqibFYF38UumNRHVuQruby+PuxAoGAEXlrLfcMf/OfdJhHWQhx\n" +
            "Hs56j4+qQ7HAwAFhrm3NeijUNb+rzcq0royziKGlLb6XsIfIKPcYHMia+vogGXz4\n" +
            "0+cBxXLsQ6JBbMGvgLYxO6MqJmoKaY3DyE2Z4/ieUgIzRqM98kFNFnrjZQ5meb3C\n" +
            "qBT8A1NNswsyX+xn6b/hooECgYBzFNF+KcYLjW0zoNgxe2869XD79TEqoghzKVac\n" +
            "7F9FwwghWWcf736B4h+a23LRTPX/DhyJvgkmHqn70nnj0KFsHDQ0rF41o/QLbyxO\n" +
            "P6uT1bvt5qMzBBeZ6yKnO4U4GdayKKivUqae/9KKN/yza+nvHKAsesvo3DR9UZGT\n" +
            "hE7EAQKBgDTAdeIqFFXsnjWAIl8gvYDbmZA+oBT5dNAHLAIxuVns42IknxHUPjHd\n" +
            "78q4VNRGGtMlxXJMJ9pwKdR1BRa4vbiloUZJqaDgU0qLkUtQ1/NE16LTuFI5B3gl\n" +
            "/d9d4AyW8kgd0fiJn5DQlLOAYJ4eU8XosjQNLh4YSHiQS7CBII6o\n" +
            "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("FindDoctorApiAdmin")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "user", "doctor", "admin")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600) 
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(2592000) 
                .and()
                    .withClient("FindDoctorApiDoctor")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "doctor")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600) 
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(2592000) 
                .and()
                    .withClient("FindDoctorApiUser")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "user")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600) 
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(2592000) 
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.prefix("/FindDoctorAPI")
                 .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                 .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                 .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                 .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);

        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomTokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    private final AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfig(AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler) {
        this.accessDeniedHandler = accessDeniedHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                 .stateless(false)
                 .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("**/rest/user/**")
                    .antMatchers("**/rest/admin/**")
                    .antMatchers("**/rest/doctor/**")
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("**/rest/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                        .antMatchers("**/rest/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                        .antMatchers("**/rest/doctor/**").access("hasRole('DOCTOR')")
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
        ;
    }

}
```

Now, when I enter the address below to get a token_access, I will encounter the message contained in the thread.

```
post --- http://localhost:8001/FindDoctorAPI/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=123
```

I searched the site a lot, but all the solutions said did not solve my problem.
Please give me some guidance and tell me where the problem is from ???

Comment: And, as instructed, did you provide Basic Auth with the client credentials?

Comment: Just a thing, you should not be posting private keys anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I did the following photos in the order below:
step 1:  http://uupload.ir/files/33d_1.png
step 2 : http://uupload.ir/files/70s9_2.png
step 3 : http://uupload.ir/files/rw0y_3.png

Comment: Always attach images to the question, rather than uploading it on an external site. I can't see these images because of websense. Anyway, make sure that client credentials you're passing is Base64 encoded and in format "clientId:clientSecret", notice colon in between credentials.